# How to set up multiple "environments" with CloudBees?

Tags: java, deployment, development-environment, cloudbees, paas

I just read all the [CloudBees developer docs](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/Main/) and was surprised I didn't see anything about setting up multiple environments for your deployment pipeline.

I plan on running my app locally, then promote the code to a QA machine inside my network, and from there it would be nice to deploy the code changes to a "Demo" environment on the CloudBees cloud, where clients could review/acceptance test the changes before I set them live.

So I ask: how does one set up both a Demo and Production environment on CloudBees?

Ideally, I'd like to have my Demo environment be `demo.myapp.example.com` and the Production environment be `myapp.example.com`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You for sure can deploy the exact same binary to multiple environment, and get each of them configured with distinct resources and parameters. This is a common pattern. You probably will need to use the cloudbees SDK to fine-grain setup both environments. Both run.cloudbees.com web console and jenkins cloudbees deployer offer limited options.

Comment: Thanks @nicolas de loof (+1) - I looked in the SDK docs but all I could find was an article on [custom application domains](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Custom+Application%20Domains). Could you point me to the documentation that would show me how to do this, or provide an example of using the SDK to set up Demo and Prod environments? Thanks again!